# trouble unit testing ember-data model using konacha

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, mocha.js, konacha

The following test will pass if I run each spec independently. If I run them in succession only the first spec will pass.

```
#= require spec_helper
#= require models/job
#= require ./fixtures/job

describe "Job", ->

  beforeEach (done) ->
    @job = App.Job.find(1)
    @job.on 'didLoad', -> done()

  it "returns property idName", ->
    expect( @job.get('idName') ).to.equal("#1 - first job")

  it "expects property idName to update if name changes", ->
    @job.set('name', 'new name')
    expect( @job.get('idName') ).to.equal("#1 - new name")

  it "expects property idName to update if originalId changes", ->
    @job.set('originalId', 7)
    expect( @job.get('idName') ).to.equal("#7 - first job")
```

The error konacha is giving me is:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded at http://localhost:3500/assets/mocha.js:4001:14
```

Anyone have any suggestions. Should I use jasmine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have a solution. I was thinking the app was initialized before each spec. It seems after the first test the job is loaded so I am checking if the job is loaded and calling the done function.

```
beforeEach (done) ->
  @job = App.Job.find(1)
  @job.on 'didLoad', -> done()

afterEach ->
  Ember.run ->
    App.reset()
```